# Which mathematical method is used by odeint?

Tags: python, c++, numerical-methods, differential-equations, odeint

I'm working with `scipy.integrate.odeint` and want to understand it better. For this I have two slightly related questions:

1. Which mathematical method is it using? Runge-Kutta? Adams-Bashforth? I found this [site](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/getting_started/overview.html), but it seems to be for C++, but as far as I know the python function uses the C++ version as well... It states that it switches automatically between implicit and explicit solver, does anybody know how it does this?
2. To understand/reuse the information I would like to know at which timepoints it evaluates the function and how exactly it computes the solution of the ODE, but fulloutput does not seem to help/I wasn't able to find out how. So to be more precise, an example with Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg: I want the different timepoints at which it evaluated f and the weights it used to multiply it.

Additional information (what for this Info is needed):
I want to reuse this information to use automatic differentiation. So I would call odeint as a black box, find out all the relevant steps it made and reuse this info to calculate the differential `dx(T_end)/dx0`.

If you know of any other method to solve my problem, please go ahead. Also if another ode solver might be more appropriate to d this.

PS: I'm new, so would it be better to split this question into to questions? I.e. seperate 1. and 2.?

Comment: [From their docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) "*Solve a system of ordinary differential equations using lsoda from the FORTRAN library odepack.*". You can [read about LSODA here](http://www.oecd-nea.org/tools/abstract/detail/uscd1227).

Comment: Yes, I've done that, unfortunately it didn't help, as most of the terms they used were unknown to me. Respectively I don't know Fortran, so I don't think that looking at the source code will help me a lot.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's the README file of odepack: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.0/scipy/integrate/odepack/readme

Comment: First part of the question has mainly been answered, does anybody know the answer to the second part?